# jQuery sum text input in table

Tags: jquery, html-table

In my code, when the button add is pressed, it creates a row in the table.

I need, in each line, when you leave the quantity or price input, the sum makes and assignes the value in the subtotal.

HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="0"  >
<tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>U$ Price</td>
<td>Subtotal</td>
    <td>Add</td>
    <td>Remove</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_clone">
    <td>
        <select style="width:200px" name="itens[]">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Item A</option>
        <option value="2">Item B</option>
        <option value="3">Item C</option>
    </td>                                            
    <td><input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" autofocus name="qtd[]" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="price[]" id="price" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="subtotal[]" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="tr_clone_remove"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_remove', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    $tr.remove();
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to make an attempt, then tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I can partly assist, try using document.getElementById to select the quantity and price fields for calculations.
DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sDMjT/
I'm not sure how to make it detect which row you're working in so it will only work for the first row.

Comment: I really don't know how code I have to try, if focusin or focusout, each. I learning jquery, and I'm a little beat lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Should be what your looking for ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6Su2/))[http://jsfiddle.net/C6Su2/]:

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="0"  >
<tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>U$ Price</td>
<td>Subtotal</td>
    <td>Add</td>
    <td>Remove</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_clone">
    <td>
        <select style="width:200px" name="itens[]">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Item A</option>
        <option value="2">Item B</option>
        <option value="3">Item C</option>
    </td>                                            
    <td><input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" name="qtd" class="quantity text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="price" class="price text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="subtotal" class="subtotal text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="tr_clone_remove"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery 1.3+ ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6Su2/)):

```
    var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_remove', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    $tr.remove();
});
$(".quantity, .price").live("keyup", function(){
    var prtCont = $(this).parent().parent();
    var prce = parseInt(prtCont.find('.price').val()) - 0;
    var qnty = parseInt(prtCont.find('.quantity').val()) - 0;
    if(!isNaN(prce) && !isNaN(qnty)){
        prtCont.find('.subtotal').val(prce * (qnty));
    }else{
        prtCont.find('.subtotal').val("");
    }
});
```

OR jQuery 1.9+ ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKjbg/))

```
var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_remove', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    $tr.remove();
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity, .price", function(){
    var prtCont = $(this).parent().parent();
    var prce = parseInt(prtCont.find('.price').val()) - 0;
    var qnty = parseInt(prtCont.find('.quantity').val()) - 0;
    if(!isNaN(prce) && !isNaN(qnty)){
        prtCont.find('.subtotal').val(prce * (qnty));
    }else{
        prtCont.find('.subtotal').val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code it is very useful to me. can you explain how to sum all subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the following changes to the html try the below code

1. Add the class `qty` to the input element `qtd`
2. Add the class `price` to the input element `price`
3. Add the class `subtotal` to the input element `subtotal`

Code

```
$('table').on('change', '.qty, .price', function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var prce = parseInt($('.price', tr).val(), 10);
    var qnty = parseInt($('.qty', tr).val(), 10);
    if(!isNaN(prce) && !isNaN(qnty)){
        $('.subtotal', tr).val(prce * (qnty));
    }else{
        $('.subtotal',tr).val("");
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bjU99/)

Comment: @MLewisCodeSolutions looks like you edited your answer after my post with jquery 1.9 solution not the other way around